# extract all text inside braces into array of strings

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a big string from which I would like to extract all parts that are inside round braces.

Say I have a string like

> "this (one) that (one two) is (three )"

I need to write a function that would return an array

```
["one", "one two", "three "]
```

I tried to write a regex from some advice found here and failed, since I seem to only get the first element and not a proper array filled with all of them: http://jsfiddle.net/gfQzK/

```
var match = s.match(/\(([^)]+)\)/);
alert(match[1]);
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? My solution does not have to be regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to change a few things.
First, add the global attribute to your regex. Now your regex should look like:

```
/\(([^)]+)\)/g
```

Then, `match.length` will provide you with the number of matches. And to extract the matches, use indexes such as `match[1]` `match[2]` `match[3]` ...

Answer (score 4):

You need a global regex. See if this helps:

```
var matches = [];
str.replace(/\(([^)]+)\)/g, function(_,m){ matches.push(m) });

console.log(matches); //= ["one", "one two", "three "]
```

`match` won't do as it doesn't capture groups in global regex. `replace` can be used to loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the global flag, and multiline if you have new lines in there, and continually `exec` the result until you have all your results in an array:

```
var s='Russia ignored (demands) by the White House to intercept the N.S.A. leaker and return him to the United States, showing the two countries (still) have a (penchant) for that old rivalry from the Soviet era.';

var re = /\(([^)]+)\)/gm, arr = [], res = [];
while ((arr = re.exec(s)) !== null) {
    res.push(arr[1]);    
}

alert(res);
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/gfQzK/4/)**

---

For reference check out this [mdn article on `exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)